How to customize set of assemblies copied in the test environment folder by BenchmarkDotNet prior to running the benchmark?
I have this issue where my NET 6.0 application requires a series of dlls when is built in Release mode that do not get copied in the GUID folder Benchmark.NET generates prior to running the benchmarks. They do exist in the installation/publication folder, but are not copied over when running the tests.
These dlls are loaded via reflection.
I tried to copy them into the current folder the benchmark is running from with a [GlobalSetup] and although the top level assemblies do get copied, there are still problems with other dlls that are dependencies of these top level assemblies and that cannot be resolved.
Is there a way to configure the files BenchmarkDotNet copies into its work/test directories?
I am using BenchmarkDotNet 0.13.12.
